# Html <div> Dynamic sizing, annoying behavior

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am fairly new to web development and I have the following  in HTML:

```
<div id="map" style='width: 97vw; height: 76vh;
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;'></div>
```

I was trying to make div section automatically adjust itself as discussed many times before and using vw, vh seemed like the simplest solution here.

However when I stretch the width of the page, I get 'jumps', it don't auto adjust itself continuously.

This is before stretching:
[image: before]

This is just after stretching a little:
[image: just after]

I am trying to keep the code clean, therefore it would be best if I can solve this using only html (yet I would still use javascript, css etc. if they provide faster/better solutions).

My goal is to have this map always ending from say 10px before the end of the entire screen, and adjust its size continuously when user stretches the page. What would be the best way to do this?

Note: I am aware similar subjects has been discussed several times before and I went through their content. However I don't think this is a duplicate because I am more concerned with the details such as 'jumps' as described in images, and I want to have a specific ending relative to end of the screen rather than just filling the page or having a ratio of it.

Comment: Well, I would use two divs. One is map with `height 100%` and `width 100%`, and another one have `padding 10px` and `width 100%` and fixed height. Link: https://jsfiddle.net/ajarjrq7/

But I seen you need relative to the page so my answer is wrong.

Comment: The "jumps" happen because the speed at which the map is repainted isn't fast enough. It does need to load more data from the web on every resize event, so you'll need a pretty fast connection and a reasonably fast computer to make that happen smoothly (with a high enough framerate).

Comment: @Ernestas Stankevičius nice suggestion, I will do that if I cant figure out anything else thank you.

Comment: @Mr Lister , But the thing is I don't get this jumps for other intervals. For example when it is smaller and I want to double the map, it just does it continuously. Jumps happen only when map has some width. Since the connection speed and additional data to be downloaded is the same for both cases, I am not sure if that might be the cause. And if that was the problem, first picture should have stretched itself after I waited for a while, but it dont. It only changes with stretching, so problem must be with <div>